# group by ratio and seniority list IN SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a MYSQL, and I am looking for a solution to show data grouping by ratio.

I have a `COURSE` table which contain courses id and courses ratio. I have another table, `ASK`, which contain askers id, and another field course id pointing on `COURSE` table (ids correspond). With one SQL query, I would like to display all asks grouping by ratio and rejecting other demands. Demands are considered by seniority list.

By example, I have 3 courses: the first one allow only 2 people and 2 other courses allow only one person. In the ASK table, we have 3 askers (JACK, JOE AND JOHN) pointing on first course, (JOHN AND JOE) 2 on second and third (JACK AND JOHN).  JACK is the older, after its JOHN and after its JOE.

I would like to see:

```
course id   studentName 
-------------------------
1           JACK         
1           JOHN            
2           JOHN
3           JACK
```

Comment: pretty confusing.  can you post table structures?

Comment: yeah of course: 

TABLE STUDENT:
studentName
seniority

TABLE COURSE
courseID
ratio

TABLE ASKS
studentName
courseID

Comment: @pier: Do I understand correctly that you want to show only "demands" (asks) that can be fulfilled (like 3 people ask to join course 1, but only 2 can be fulfilled, according to seniority). And a person has no restrictions, if the oldest asks for all courses, he'll get all course, right?

Comment: @ypercube: Not exactly. Its like in a compagny by exemple: the older chose before the younger... And, i want to display the list of every course (or job or anything) with the "winner". If anybody ask the job or the ratio is not fulled, Just display null as winner.. I am not clear.. I speak french.. Its hard to translate..

Comment: I tought to a simple solution: removing ratio field from COURSE, and just having to course with the same ID in COURSE TABLE and just display rows of this table. Here, again, i dont know to join only 2 older askers FROM N asks to my COURSE table.. I dont know if you understand my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.courseID
       s.studentName
FROM course AS c
    JOIN asks AS a
        ON a.courseID = c.courseID
    JOIN student AS s
        ON s.studentName = a.studentName
    JOIN asks AS a2
        ON a2.courseID = c.courseID
    JOIN student AS s2
        ON s2.studentName = a2.studentName
        AND s2.seniority <= s.seniority
GROUP BY c.courseID
       , c.ratio
       , s.studentName
HAVING c.ratio >= COUNT(*)
ORDER BY c.courseID
       , s.seniority
```

Comment: @pier: It would be best if you edited your question and added the sample data (like what `SELECT * FROM course`, and the 2 other tables show).

Comment: Unknown column 'c.ratio' in 'having clause' just before order by.. odd.. if I remove it, alias C works

Comment: @pier: There are two side-effects: If you have courses that no-one has asked for, they will not be shown.

Comment: Yeah, i realised that! Its impossible that two person have the same seniority (in my context). Otherwise, if nobody ask for the course, its perfect cause the course will be given. Thank you for everything

Comment: And if two or more persons have same seniority and have asked same course, they either both will be shown or none of them (for that course).